# Creating a json output in python

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I am trying to return a response for a function in json form. The output is a list with each element being a dictionary. I don't see any mistake when I print the output. The problem arises when I iterate through the output. I get all the characters in the output one by one. See the sample code and sample output for proper understanding.

code:

```
import requests
import json
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import OrderedDict

class Cricbuzz():
    url = "http://synd.cricbuzz.com/j2me/1.0/livematches.xml"
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def getxml(self,url):
        try:
            r = requests.get(url)
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e: 
            print e
            sys.exit(1)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
        return soup

    def matchinfo(self,match):
        d = OrderedDict()
        d['id'] = match['id']
        d['srs'] = match['srs']
        d['mchdesc'] = match['mchdesc']
        d['mnum'] = match['mnum']
        d['type'] = match['type']
        d['mchstate'] = match.state['mchstate']
        d['status'] = match.state['status']
        return d

    def matches(self):
        xml = self.getxml(self.url)
        matches = xml.find_all('match')
        info = []
        for match in matches:
            info.append(self.matchinfo(match))
        data = json.dumps(info)
        return data 
c = Cricbuzz()
matches = c.matches()
print matches #print matches -  output1
for match in matches:
    print match #print match -  output2
```

"print matches" i.e output1 in above code gives me following output:

```
[
    {
        "status": "Coming up on Dec 24 at 01:10 GMT", 
        "mchstate": "nextlive", 
        "mchdesc": "AKL vs WEL", 
        "srs": "McDonalds Super Smash, 2016-17", 
        "mnum": "18TH MATCH", 
        "type": "ODI", 
        "id": "0"
    }, 
    {
        "status": "Ind U19 won by 34 runs", 
        "mchstate": "Result", 
        "mchdesc": "INDU19 vs SLU19", 
        "srs": "Under 19 Asia Cup, 2016", 
        "mnum": "Final", 
        "type": "ODI", 
        "id": "17727"
    }, 
    {
        "status": "PRS won by 48 runs", 
        "mchstate": "Result", 
        "mchdesc": "PRS vs ADS", 
        "srs": "Big Bash League, 2016-17", 
        "mnum": "5th Match", 
        "type": "T20", 
        "id": "16729"
    }
]
```

But "print match" i.e output2 in above code inside the for loop gives this output:

```
[
    {
    "
    i
    d
    "
    :

    "
    0
    "
    ,

    "
    s
    r
    s
    "
    :

    "
    M
    c
    D
    o
    n
    a
    l
    d
    s

    S
    u
    p
    e
    r

    S
    m
    a
    s
    h
    ,

    2
    0
    1
    6
    -
    1
    7
    "
    ,

    "
    m
    c
    h
    d
    e
    s
```

As you can see,a character gets printed on each line from matches. I would like to get the dictionary object when printing the match.

Comment: You cannot, because you *serialized* your Python object into JSON, which is a string-based encoding. You either have to deserialize what is returned by `match` or don't use `json.dumps`

Comment: You serialized the return data and that means you iterate the serialized string, not the pre-serialized objects. JSON is a serialized data format useful for saving to files or passing to other programs but is pretty much useless for processing in a program. Just pass the python objects back... you don't need to jsonize them.

Comment: serializing in json also defeats the ordering of the list with OrderedDict.  dictionaries are inherently _un_ordered in json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    def matches(self):
        xml = self.getxml(self.url)
        matches = xml.find_all('match')
        info = []
        for match in matches:
            info.append(self.matchinfo(match))
        data = json.dumps(info) # This is a string
        return data             # This is a string

c = Cricbuzz()
matches = c.matches()           # This is a string
print matches 
for match in matches:           # Looping over all characters of a string
    print match
```

I think you just want `return info`, which is a list. You can `json.dumps()` outside of that function at a later point when you actually do need JSON.

Or if you do want that function to return a JSON string, then you have to parse it back into a list.

```
for match in json.loads(matches):
```

Comment: If I just return the info, I get the following output - http://pastebin.com/yAg2QFyn.  "OrdereDict" is even coming in the output.

Comment: Sure... You are printing an entire object. Or the `repr()` of an `OrderedDict`.

Comment: In other words, that's not wrong, and I don't know what else you expected

Answer (score 1):

If you call `json.dumps` like you do on `info` before returning `data`, the value is converted to a json *string*.  If you want to iterate over the iterable the json string *represents*, you have to load the data back out of the json.

Consider:

```
import json

info = [ { "a": 1}, { "b": 2} ]
data = json.dumps(info,indent=2)
print data
for i in data:
    print i
for i in json.loads(data):
    print i


$ python t.py
[
  {
    "a": 1
  },
  {
    "b": 2
  }
]
[




{






"
a
"
:

1




}
,





{








"
b
"
:

2




}


]
{u'a': 1}
{u'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

`matches` is a JSON string, not a dictionary, so `for match in matches:` iterates over the characters in the string.

If you want the dictionary, the function should return `info` rather than `json.dumps(info)`. Or you could do:

```
for match in json.loads(matches):
```

to parse the JSON back into a dictionary.

Normally you should move data around in the program as structured types like dictionaries and lists, and only convert them to/from JSON when you're sending over a network or storing into a file.

Answer (score 0):

Json.dumps returns a string.

If you expect to have each dict from list during iteration process you may wrap your response into:

```
matches = json.loads(matches)
```

Btw, it's nice to dumps it's previously as a simple JSON validation, because it makes a valid JSON from invalid: first of all replaces single quotes with double quotes, etc. That's why I suggest don't skip json.dumps as you're trying to do.